# rails change boolean value within a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi everyone I need help with this method:
I have a method that loops trough two models' data and compare them; if a match is found, I want to set the **nih_pub** match attribute to true then return all nih_pub that have match as false.
it woks well if I use the commented if statement `if nih.pubyear == "2003" and  nih.pmid == "12538806"`, but it is not working with the looping.

below is the method i am using:

```
def compare
  nih_pub = NihPublication.where(user: current_user).all
  pubmed_pub = Publication.where(user: current_user).all

  nih_pub.each{ |nih|
    pubmed_pub.each {|pubmed|
      if nih.pubyear == pubmed.publication_year and  nih.pmid == pubmed.pubmed_id
      # if nih.pubyear == "2003" and  nih.pmid == "12538806"
        nih.match = true
        nih.save!
      end
    }
  }

  @missing = nih_pub.where(match: false)
end
```

Thank for your help

Comment: It's unclear: are you having an issue with the condition logic of the uncommented `if` (and the commented `if` worked correctly) OR are you having a problem with exiting the loop?

Comment: you can write `return` statement in `if` condition, so it return from loop and gives you `@missing` as output.

Comment: Sorry; the problem i am having is that this code is not getting executed `nih.match = true nih.save!`. if i use the commented if statement, everything works.

Comment: Thank everyone, it finally worked after I changed the if statement to this:`if nih.pubyear == "#{pubmed.publication_year}" and  nih.pmid == "#{pubmed.pubmed_id}"
           #if nih.pubyear == "2003" and  nih.pmid == "12538806"
              nih.match = true
              nih.save!
            end`

Comment: Sounds like you'll accept @ChrisPeters answer, then.  :D

Comment: @Idriss Try this instead: `if nih.pubyear == pubmed.publication_year.to_s and nih.pmid == pubmed.pubmed_id.to_s`

Comment: @Idriss Or ahh, I see you're using `to_i` instead based on your comment on my answer. Hopefully you're more aware of the awesomeness of `to_i` and `to_s` by playing around with this a little. :)

Comment: by the way you dont need to call .all method after .where. `NihPublication.where(user: current_user)` would work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a data type issue. You can compare data types in your console like this:

```
def compare
  nih_pub = NihPublication.where(user: current_user).all
  pubmed_pub = Publication.where(user: current_user).all

  nih_pub.each{ |nih|
    pubmed_pub.each { |pubmed|
      puts "nih.pubyear #{nih.pubyear.class.name}" 
      puts "pubmed.publication_year #{pubmed.publication_year.class.name}"
      puts "nih.pmid #{nih.pmid.class.name}"
      puts "pubmed.pubmed_id #{pubmed.pubmed_id.class.name}"

      if nih.pubyear == pubmed.publication_year and nih.pmid == pubmed.pubmed_id
      # if nih.pubyear == "2003" and  nih.pmid == "12538806"
        nih.match = true
        nih.save!
      end
    }
  }

  @missing = nih_pub.where(match: false)
end
```

If you see something like this:

```
nih.pubyear Integer
pubmed.publication_year String
nih.pmid Integer
pubmed.pubmed_id String
```

Then you know that you'll need to cast values when comparing them.

I suspect that you'll need to change your code to something like this (though this is only a guess and is based on the debug output I have listed above):

```
def compare
  nih_pub = NihPublication.where(user: current_user).all
  pubmed_pub = Publication.where(user: current_user).all

  nih_pub.each{ |nih|
    pubmed_pub.each { |pubmed|
      # Cast those strings to integers so you're comparing apples to apples.
      if nih.pubyear == pubmed.publication_year.to_i and nih.pmid == pubmed.pubmed_id.to_i
        nih.match = true
        nih.save!
      end
    }
  }

  @missing = nih_pub.where(match: false)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i am using `.to_i` instead of `"#{}"`